# Det of matrix $4\times 4$

Tags: matrices, determinant

Is the method of calculating determinant of $3\times 3$ matrix by diagonals,
apply also on $4\times 4$ matrix?

for example:

$$\begin{matrix}2&2&1&3|\\1&4&4&5|\\5&1&1&6|\\7&1&4&5|\end{matrix}\begin{matrix}2&2&1\\1&4&4\\5&1&1\\7&1&4\end{matrix}$$

$\det = 2\cdot4\cdot1\cdot5+\dotsb+3\cdot1\cdot1\cdot4 - 7\cdot1\cdot4\cdot3-\dotsb-5\cdot5\cdot4\cdot1 = 171$

Is this valid?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! I don't understand what your ‘method’ is, nor what the matrix is?

Comment: @NaorYehuda Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the [**Rule of Sarrus**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) is only valid for 3-by -3 matrices, in general for n-by -n matrices we can refer to [**Laplace expansion**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) method, that is by the first row

$$\begin{vmatrix}
2&   2&   1&   3\\
1&  4&   4&   5\\
5&   1&   1&   6\\
7&   1&   4&   5
\end{vmatrix}=2\begin{vmatrix}
4&   4&   5\\
  1&   1&   6\\
  1&   4&   5
\end{vmatrix}-2\begin{vmatrix}
1&    4&   5\\
5&      1&   6\\
7&     4&   5
\end{vmatrix}+1\begin{vmatrix}
1&  4&    5\\
5&   1&      6\\
7&   1&     5
\end{vmatrix}-3\begin{vmatrix}
1&  4&   4   \\
5&   1&   1   \\
7&   1&   4   
\end{vmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2):

The fastest method is Gaussian  elimination to obtain a triangular matrix – in this case the determinant is the product of the diagonal elements:
\begin{align}
&\begin{vmatrix}
2&2&1&3\\1&4&4&5\\5&1&1&6\\7&1&4&5
\end{vmatrix}
=-\begin{vmatrix}
1&4&4&5\\2&2&1&3\\5&1&1&6\\7&1&4&5
\end{vmatrix}
=-\begin{vmatrix}\begin{array}{rrrr}
1&4&4&5\\0&-6&-7&-7\\0&-19&-19&-19\\0&-27&-24&-30
\end{array}\end{vmatrix}=19\times 3\begin{vmatrix}\begin{array}{rrrr}
1&4&4&5\\0&6&7&7\\0&1&1&1\\0&9&8&10
\end{array}\end{vmatrix}\\[1ex]
=&-19\times 3\begin{vmatrix}\begin{array}{rrrr}
1&4&4&5\\0&1&1&1\\0&6&7&7\\0&9&8&10
\end{array}\end{vmatrix}=-19\times 3\begin{vmatrix}\begin{array}{rrrr}
1&4&4&5\\0&1&1&1\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&-1&1
\end{array}\end{vmatrix}
=-19\times 3\begin{vmatrix}
1&4&4&5\\0&1&1&1\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&2
\end{vmatrix}=-114\\
&
\end{align}

However, in the case of $4\times4$ matrices, you have two other possibilities, for a computation by blocks:

- If $M=\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&D \end{pmatrix}$ is a $4×4$ matrix consisting of blocks of size $2$, and if $CD=DC$, then we can compute a $2×2$ determinant:
  $$\det M=\det(AD-BC).$$
- We can use Laplace's expansion *along the first two columns*. To explain the computation, we introduce some notations:

\begin{array}{ll}
p_{ij}&\text{is the $2×2$ determinant of rows $i$ and $j$ of the first two columns},\\
q_{ij}&\text{is the $2×2$ determinant of rows $i$ and $j$ of the last two columns.}
\end{array}
With these notations, one has
$$\det M=p_{12}q_{34}+p_{13}q_{42}+p_{14}q_{23}+q_{12}p_{34}+q_{13}p_{42}+q_{14}p_{23}.$$

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not valid. My computation using Octave shows that the determinant is negative.

```
octave:1> A = [ 2 2 1 3; 1 4 4 5; 5 1 1 6; 7 1 4 5]
A =

   2   2   1   3
   1   4   4   5
   5   1   1   6
   7   1   4   5

octave:2> det(A)
ans = -114.00
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't valid.  When you calculate the determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix by minors, you compute $n!$ products.  When $n=3, n!=6$ and there are $6$ broken diagonals, and the "spaghetti rule" still involves $6$ products.  But when $n=4, n!=24,$ and there are only $8$ broken diagonals, so there isn't much hope.

You can easily come up with examples to prove it doesn't work.  <s>(In fact, I imagine it's harder to come up with examples where it *does* work.)</s>